# is there a native php function which can escape strings with umlautes correctly for postresql?

Tags: php, postgresql, diacritics

i used the functions `pg_escape_bytea()` and `pg_escape_string()` but i had to find out that there are several problems with umlautes:

if i do `pg_escape_bytea("pöl")` , where "pöl" is utf8 i get "`p\\303\\266l`", and i cannot compare this with my values in the tabels ... so what can i do?

have somebody written a function so far, which escapes my string correctly with umlauts?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use [pg_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php) or p[g_query_params()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php) to escape a string as a string? The value "pöl" doesn't look like binary data, it looks like a string.

Comment: okay thats right, but i also escap JSON with it, and there are several problems with slashes then...

Comment: JSON is still a string, so you still need a string-function to escape. Both pg_escape_string and pg_query_params will do fine, just start testing.

Comment: you are right! after trying severl differnt ways i had somwhere something in the code which destroyed the handling. wrote the concering parts new, and works like a charm :-) thanks